# Как сохранить сообщения пользователя в телеграм боте питон?(Telebot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
if call.data == 'settings':
    bot.send.message(message.chat.id, text='Путь к прокси: {number_proxy1}')

if call.data == 'data_card':
    data_card2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    data_number = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Путь к ПРОКСИ', callback_data='data_number')
    card_data = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Путь к ЛОГИНУ', callback_data='card_login')
    data_cvv = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Путь к ПАРОЛЮ', callback_data='data_pass')
    back6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='back6')
    data_card2.row(data_number)
    data_card2.row(ard_login)
    data_card2.row(data_pass)
    data_card2.row(back6)

    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=f'? Выбери, какие данные хочешь указать?', reply_markup=data_card2)


if call.data == 'data_number':
    number_proxy = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='? Строго следующим сообщением отправь мне путь к файлу с прокси:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(number_proxy, save_number)

def save_number(message):
    global number_proxy1
    number_proxy1 = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Путь: {number_proxy1} сохранен!')
```

Понимаю что ошибка из-за того что вся функция вообще ниже сообщения, в котором должен сохраниться путь, но я не могу придумать как по другому сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Забыл написать, нужно чтобы в 2 строке сообщения сохранялся путь, но кидает ошибку: NameError: name 'number_cards' is not defined

Comment: Я не вижу в вашем коде number_cards от слова совсем